# why my pascal triangle program not giving proper formatting?

Tags: java, tabs, formatting, output

I write my own logic to print pascal triangle. That has following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pascal {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("please enter height of pascal triangle :");
        int Heightchk = 0, Height = sc.nextInt();
        if (Height > 0) {
            MYarray PascalArray = new MYarray();
            PascalArray.setLength(Height * 2 - 1);
            PascalArray.IntilizeA(PascalArray.A);
            if (Height == 1) {
                PascalArray.printArray(PascalArray.A);
            } else {
                while (Heightchk < Height) {
                    PascalArray.printArray(PascalArray.A);
                    Heightchk += 1;
                    if (Heightchk < Height) {
                        PascalArray.reSet(PascalArray.B);
                        PascalArray.setElements(PascalArray.A, PascalArray.B);

                        PascalArray.printArray(PascalArray.B);
                        Heightchk += 1;
                        if (Heightchk < Height) {
                            PascalArray.reSet(PascalArray.A);
                            PascalArray.setElements(PascalArray.B, PascalArray.A);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't Draw pascal Triangle of this Height");
        }
    }
}

class MYarray {
    String[] A, B;
    void IntilizeA(String[] Array) {
        Array[(Array.length - 1) / 2] = "1";
    }
    void setLength(int length) {
        A = new String[length];
        B = new String[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            A[i] = "\t";
            B[i] = "\t";
        }
    }
    void reSet(String[] Array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            Array[i] = "\t";
        }
    }
    void printArray(String[] Array) {
        for (String Element : Array) {
            System.out.print(Element);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
    void setElements(String[] from, String[] to) {
        for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
            if (from[i] != "\t") {
                if (to[i - 1] == "\t") {
                    to[i - 1] = "0";
                }
                if (to[i + 1] == "\t") {
                    to[i + 1] = "0";
                }
                to[i - 1] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(to[i - 1]) + Integer.valueOf(from[i]));
                to[i + 1] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(to[i + 1]) + Integer.valueOf(from[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logic that I applied working super fine but, still there is a problem with alignment of elements.
It's giving the following output:

```
    please enter height of pascal triangle :5
                1               


            1   1           


        1   2   1       


    1   3   3   1
```

while it's output should be like this:

```
    please enter height of pascal triangle :5
                1               


            1       1           


        1       2       1       


    1       3       3       1   


1       4       6       4       1
```

What is problem with my logic. How can i make it right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pascal triangle proper formatting java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371775/pascal-triangle-proper-formatting-java), and [Pascal triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818341/pascal-triangle), and some [230 others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pascal+triangle+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: @Mogsdad actually i write the above code but getting in proper output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine. But when you are replacing a tab `\t` with any number, you are eventually removing that much indentation for that array.

For example, In your first array
1 is the 4th element which is center element. That means it has 4 tabs before center of Array.

While in second Array, before center index, you have replaced one of tabs with 1, so indentation of 2nd Array and eventually center of Array is shifted to left with 1 tab.

This continues for next Arrays. So your formatting gets wrong. To handle this, don't replace tab with number, rather append the number to the `\t`. This will make sure your indentation is intact.

Below is the updated code. Also I updated your code to follow standard naming conventions

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pascal {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("plese enter height of pascal tringle :");
        int heightchk = 0, height = sc.nextInt();
        if (height > 0) {
            MyArray pascalArray = new MyArray();
            pascalArray.setLength(height * 2 - 1);
            pascalArray.IntilizeA(pascalArray.a);
            if (height == 1) {
                pascalArray.printArray(pascalArray.a);
            } else {
                while (heightchk < height) {
                    pascalArray.printArray(pascalArray.a);
                    heightchk += 1;
                    if (heightchk < height) {
                        pascalArray.reSet(pascalArray.b);
                        pascalArray.setElements(pascalArray.a, pascalArray.b);

                        pascalArray.printArray(pascalArray.b);
                        heightchk += 1;
                        if (heightchk < height) {
                            pascalArray.reSet(pascalArray.a);
                            pascalArray.setElements(pascalArray.b, pascalArray.a);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't Drow pascal Tringle of this Height");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}

class MyArray {
    String[] a, b;
    void IntilizeA(String[] array) {
        array[(array.length - 1) / 2] = "\t1";
    }
    void setLength(int length) {
        a = new String[length];
        b = new String[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = "\t";
            b[i] = "\t";
        }
    }
    void reSet(String[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = "\t";
        }
    }
    void printArray(String[] array) {
        for (String element : array) {
            System.out.print(element);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    void setElements(String[] from, String[] to) {
        for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
            if (from[i] != "\t") {
                if (to[i - 1] == "\t") {
                    to[i - 1] = "0";
                }
                if (to[i + 1] == "\t") {
                    to[i + 1] = "0";
                }
                to[i - 1] = "\t"+String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(to[i - 1].trim()) + Integer.valueOf(from[i].trim()));
                to[i + 1] = "\t"+String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(to[i + 1].trim()) + Integer.valueOf(from[i].trim()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
                1               
            1       1           
        1       2       1       
    1       3       3       1   
1       4       6       4       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the height, you can deduce the width of the final line. Half of that is the middle, which is where the first line should start, horizontally. For each additional line, start a couple more spaces before the middle.

Comment: sorry but i do not understand  @Trow Way